# Boto3 HTTP/HTTPS Proxy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following issue:

I have a S3 Storage from where I pull some files and I use boto3 to download/upload them.

This a part from my python script

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

def do_something( endpoint_url,
        key_id,
        access_key,
        region_name,
        bucket,
        file_name,) {

   proxies={
    "http": os.environ.get("HTTP_PROXY") # http://company-proxy:port
   }
   s3_config = Config(
        region_name=region_name,
        signature_version='s3v4',
        proxies=proxies,
    )
   s3 = boto3.resource(
        "s3",
        endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
        aws_access_key_id=key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=access_key,
        config=s3_config,
    )
  s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(...)
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting timeouts and this is the log output: https://pastebin.com/Sc3fGrYW
I know I use an HTTP protocol proxy for HTTPS connections, and I also found this issue that relates to my problem: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2697

Also, this is my docker file that I use to publish the python script to company's registry

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev -y

RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN pip install sqlalchemy
RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install botocore
RUN pip install openpyxl
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install datetime
RUN pip install urllib3==1.25.4 # idk about this?

ADD main.py /
ADD util/* /util/
ADD task/* /task/
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=http://company-proxy:port
ENTRYPOINT ["python","/main.py"]
CMD []
```

Thank you in advance!

I tried using the links I provided in the issue, but I didn't get that far

Comment: You need to set a `https` proxy, even if it points to a http URL to proxy traffic.  Otherwise, boto3 will attempt to connect directly to the S3 endpoint.

Comment: That seemed to work, thanks so much